# How to trigger a keyupevent in a selenium webdriver using Python?

Tags: python, selenium

A site i'm using has an input box, that when something is entered shows a list. But when using keyboard libraries such as pyautogui and keyboard anything "typed" into this input box does not trigger the keyupevent.

To elaborate, it seems that anytime a library is used to type something it doesn't cause the keyup event, I need this to happen as I need the information that the list brings up after.

This seems to be what the problem is but wasn't fixed: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5786

I can show my problem here:

on this [site](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup) there is an example of onkeyup,

run this code and click on the input box and you'll see your letters are not capitalized - this is true of all keyboard libraries including selenium I have tried

```
import time
import keyboard

time.sleep(5)

keyboard.press('a')
keyboard.press('b')
keyboard.press('v')
```

Answer (score 0):

`.key_up(...)` should send it, according to [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/keyboard/#keyup)

Comment: Have tried this before with something like, action.key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform(), did not work to trigger the event